# Displaying a list of data in a WinForm coming from a generic list whose type is known

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

So, I am quite new at all of this stuff.
I got a `IEnumerable<BasicClient>` return type from a REST call. 
I have vague memories of there being some way to bind a 
list to .NET controls but for the life of me I can't remember how to do it.

Anybody's got a pointer for me, please?

Comment: to which control do you want to bind the data??

Comment: I was thinking a ListView would be great, but a ListBox is just fine as well for my purposes. This is just to ensure I am doing the right things and, you know, that it actually works as intended :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very basic example how to bind a collection to a `ListBox`. Since I don't know `BasicClient` I demonstrate it with this class:

```
public class Poco
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a `Form` with a `ListBox` named `listBox1`. The `Form` has a field `_pocos` as `List<Poco>`. To use an `IEnumerable` as in your question I declared a property `IEnumerable<Poco> Pocos` that returns that field.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly List<Poco> _pocos = new List<Poco>();
    public IEnumerable<Poco> Pocos { get { return _pocos; }} 

    public Form1()
    {
        _pocos.AddRange(new[] {
            new Poco {Name = "Poco1", Description = "Description1"},
            new Poco {Name = "Poco2", Description = "Description2"}
        });

        InitializeComponent();

        listBox1.DataSource = Pocos;
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    }
```

As you can see, I set the `listBox1.DataSource` to this property `Pocos` and use the `listBox1.DisplayMember` property to tell the `ListBox` which member it shall display.

This is the result:

[image]

For multi-column controls this might be a little more complicated, but there are examples on the MSDN. Search for keywords `DataSource` and `DisplayMember`.

Comment: D'oh! A list box will do for my example :) Thanks! Can't wait to try it on Monday :)